# Add column to Spark dataframe with the max value that is less than the current record's value

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a Spark dataframe similar to the following:

```
id  claim_id                 service_date                  status   product
123 10606134411906233408    2018-09-17T00:00:00.000+0000    PD      blue
123 10606147900401009928    2019-01-24T00:00:00.000+0000    PD      yellow
123 10606160940704723994    2019-05-23T00:00:00.000+0000    RV      yellow
123 10606171648203079553    2019-08-29T00:00:00.000+0000    RJ      blue
123 10606186611407311724    2020-01-13T00:00:00.000+0000    PD      blue
```

Forgive me for not pasting any code as nothing has worked.  I want to add a new column with the max(service_date) of a previous row where the status is PD and the product of the current row = the product of the previous row.

This is easily done with a correlated subquery but is not efficient and, besides, is not doable in Spark because non-equi joins are not supported.  Also note that LAG will not work because I do not always require the immediate preceding record (and offset would be dynamic).

The expected output would be something such as this:

```
id  claim_id                 service_date                  status   product     previous_service_date
    123 10606134411906233408    2018-09-17T00:00:00.000+0000    PD      blue
    123 10606147900401009928    2019-01-24T00:00:00.000+0000    PD      yellow
    123 10606160940704723994    2019-05-23T00:00:00.000+0000    RV      yellow      2019-01-24T00:00:00.000+0000
    123 10606171648203079553    2019-08-29T00:00:00.000+0000    RJ      blue        2018-09-17T00:00:00.000+0000
    123 10606186611407311724    2020-01-13T00:00:00.000+0000    PD      blue        2018-09-17T00:00:00.000+0000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following which uses `max` as a window function with `when` (a case expression) but focuses on the preceding rows

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window


df = df.withColumn('previous_service_date',F.max(
    F.when(F.col("status")=="PD",F.col("service_date")).otherwise(None)
).over(
    Window.partitionBy("product")
          .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,-1)
))

df.orderBy('service_date').show(truncate=False)
```

```
+---+--------------------+-------------------+------+-------+---------------------+
|id |claim_id            |service_date       |status|product|previous_service_date|
+---+--------------------+-------------------+------+-------+---------------------+
|123|10606134411906233408|2018-09-17 00:00:00|PD    |blue   |null                 |
|123|10606147900401009928|2019-01-24 00:00:00|PD    |yellow |null                 |
|123|10606160940704723994|2019-05-23 00:00:00|RV    |yellow |2019-01-24 00:00:00  |
|123|10606171648203079553|2019-08-29 00:00:00|RJ    |blue   |2018-09-17 00:00:00  |
|123|10606186611407311724|2020-01-13 00:00:00|PD    |blue   |2018-09-17 00:00:00  |
+---+--------------------+-------------------+------+-------+---------------------+
```

**Edit 1**

You may also use `last` as denoted below

```py
df = df.withColumn('previous_service_date',F.last(
    F.when(F.col("status")=="PD" ,F.col("service_date")).otherwise(None),True
).over(
    Window.partitionBy("product")
          .orderBy('service_date')
          .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,-1)
))
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: This is working as expected: thank you.  Quick follow-up; can I refactor this to have it match also on the product?  In other words, provide the previous service date where the status is 'PD' but, also, where the previous record's product matches the current record's product?

Comment: @MichaelBass It currently does this with the help of the `partitionBy("product")`. The filter using `  F.when(F.col("status")=="PD" ,F.col("service_date"))` was applied as such since the only service dates being considered were those with a `PD` status. Do you have other test cases/data where the results are not as expected?

Comment: Sorry about my previous comment, you are correct.  I was messing around with the code and inadvertently changed the partition.  This works great and is much much appreciated.  I will be as smart as you some day.

Answer (score 0):

You can `copy` your DataFrame to a new DataFrame (`df2`) and `join` both as below:

```
(df.join(df2, 
         on = [df.Service_date > df2.Service_date,
               df.product == df2.product,
               df2.status == 'PD'],
         how = "left"))
```

The drop the duplicated columns and rename the `df2.Service_date` to `previous_service_date`

Comment: Thanks for this.  It's a nice solution but doesn't work in my scenario as it returns multiple records.